# confluence.update_page - add a change comment possible?

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I user the [python-confluence-API](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/confluence.html?highlight=history#page-actions) which gives the
`confluence.update_page(page_id, title, body, parent_id=None, type='page', representation='storage', minor_edit=False, full_width=False)`
method. I see no way to add a change comment like editing in the confluence GUI. Is this possible via the python API at all?

Comment: Is there any news on this?